# How do you catch this exception?

Tags: python, django, exception

This code is in django/db/models/fields.py  It creates/defines an exception?

```
class ReverseSingleRelatedObjectDescriptor(six.with_metaclass(RenameRelatedObjectDescriptorMethods)):
    # This class provides the functionality that makes the related-object
    # managers available as attributes on a model class, for fields that have
    # a single "remote" value, on the class that defines the related field.
    # In the example "choice.poll", the poll attribute is a
    # ReverseSingleRelatedObjectDescriptor instance.
    def __init__(self, field_with_rel):
        self.field = field_with_rel
        self.cache_name = self.field.get_cache_name()

    @cached_property
    def RelatedObjectDoesNotExist(self):
        # The exception can't be created at initialization time since the
        # related model might not be resolved yet; `rel.to` might still be
        # a string model reference.
        return type(
            str('RelatedObjectDoesNotExist'),
            (self.field.rel.to.DoesNotExist, AttributeError),
            {}
        )
```

This is in django/db/models/fields/related.py it raises the said exception above:

```
def __get__(self, instance, instance_type=None):
    if instance is None:
        return self
    try:
        rel_obj = getattr(instance, self.cache_name)
    except AttributeError:
        val = self.field.get_local_related_value(instance)
        if None in val:
            rel_obj = None
        else:
            params = dict(
                (rh_field.attname, getattr(instance, lh_field.attname))
                for lh_field, rh_field in self.field.related_fields)
            qs = self.get_queryset(instance=instance)
            extra_filter = self.field.get_extra_descriptor_filter(instance)
            if isinstance(extra_filter, dict):
                params.update(extra_filter)
                qs = qs.filter(**params)
            else:
                qs = qs.filter(extra_filter, **params)
            # Assuming the database enforces foreign keys, this won't fail.
            rel_obj = qs.get()
            if not self.field.rel.multiple:
                setattr(rel_obj, self.field.related.get_cache_name(), instance)
        setattr(instance, self.cache_name, rel_obj)
    if rel_obj is None and not self.field.null:
        raise self.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist(
            "%s has no %s." % (self.field.model.__name__, self.field.name)
        )
    else:
        return rel_obj
```

The problem is that this code:

```
    try:
        val = getattr(obj, attr_name)
    except related.ReverseSingleRelatedObjectDescriptor.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist:
        val = None  # Does not catch the thrown exception
    except Exception as foo:
        print type(foo)  # Catches here, not above
```

won't catch that exception

```
>>>print type(foo)
<class 'django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist'>
>>>isinstance(foo, related.FieldDoesNotExist)
False
```

and

```
except related.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist:
```

Raises an `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'RelatedObjectDoesNotExist'`

```
>>>isinstance(foo, related.ReverseSingleRelatedObjectDescriptor.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <fragment>
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a class, type, or tuple of classes and types
```

which is probably why.

Comment: How have you imported `related`?

Comment: use `AttributeError` instead of `related.ReverseSingleRelatedObjectDescriptor.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist`

Comment: Yes @JohnZwinck I have imported related.

Answer (score 372, accepted):

If your related model is called Foo you can just do:

```
except Foo.DoesNotExist:
```

Django is amazing when it's not terrifying. `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist` is a property that returns a type that is figured out dynamically at runtime. That type uses `self.field.rel.to.DoesNotExist` as a base class.

According to Django documentation:

> #### [DoesNotExist](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/class/#doesnotexist)
>
> *exception* **Model.DoesNotExist**
>
> This exception is raised by the ORM when an expected object is not
> found. For example, **`QuerySet.get()`** will raise it when no object
> is found for the given lookups.
>
> Django provides a **`DoesNotExist`** exception as an attribute of
> each model class to identify the class of object that could not be
> found, allowing you to catch exceptions for a particular model class.
>
> The exception is a subclass of  **`django.core.exceptions.ObjectDoesNotExist`**.

This is the magic that makes that happen. Once the model has been built up, `self.field.rel.to.DoesNotExist` is the does-not-exist exception for that model.

Comment: Because the bug was in DjangoRestFramework, and the model is somewhat hard to come by at that point.  I settled for catching ObjectDoesNotExist.

Comment: You can also use AttributeError, which under certain circumstances may be a better option (this error almost always occurs when you are accessing the "attribute" of a record, so this way you don't have to keep track whether this attribute corresponds to a record or not.

Comment: Yeaaaa okay. But why can't it just return None? Especially with one-to-one fields. Or is there a good reason?

Comment: This is all because of how the `hasattr` logic was changed in python 3. In order to work with `hasattr` it must be an exception that derives from the AttributeError class. Yet it must be also an exception that comes from the Model.DoesNotExist class.

Answer (score 74):

If you don't want to import the related model class, you can:

```
except MyModel.related_field.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist:
```

or

```
except my_model_instance._meta.model.related_field.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist:
```

where `related_field` is the field name.

Comment: this is actually pretty useful in case you need to avoid circular imports. Thanks

Answer (score 62):

Let's say we have the following models:

```
class MainModel(Model):
    pass

class RelatedModel(Model):
    main = OneToOneField(MainModel, null=True, related_name="related")
```

You can get a `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist` exception with `MainModel().related`.

You have three options for catching this exception, which you can find by looking at `.__class__.__mro__` of the exception:

1. `MainModel.related.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist`
2. `RelatedModel.DoesNotExist`
3. `django.core.exceptions.ObjectDoesNotExist`

## MainModel.related.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist

`RelatedObjectDoesNotExist` is what the question is looking for, but is specific to a nullable `OneToOneField`:

```
try:
    # Your code here
except MainModel.related.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist:
    # Handle exception
```

## RelatedModel.DoesNotExist

`Model.DoesNotExist` is the parent class of `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist`.  To catch it requires you to be able to import the model in question, but is a more generically useful code pattern.

```
try:
    # Your code here
except OtherModel.DoesNotExist:
    # Handle exception
```

## django.core.exceptions.ObjectDoesNotExist

`ObjectDoesNotExist` is the parent class of `Model.DoesNotExist`.  This will catch this exception for any model, which is helpful if you don't know what model will raise the exception:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

try:
    # Your code here
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    # Handle exception
```

Comment: I found this didn't actually catch the error as expected. The `<Model>.DoesNotExist` did

Comment: @EricBlum <Model>.DoesNotExist is a descendant of ObjectDoesNotExist, so that shouldn't happen.  Can you dig into why it is happening or give more details about your code?

Answer (score 12):

The `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist` exception is created dynamically at runtime.  Here is the relevant code snippet for the `ForwardManyToOneDescriptor` and `ReverseOneToOneDescriptor` descriptors:

```
@cached_property
def RelatedObjectDoesNotExist(self):
    # The exception can't be created at initialization time since the
    # related model might not be resolved yet; `self.field.model` might
    # still be a string model reference.
    return type(
        'RelatedObjectDoesNotExist',
        (self.field.remote_field.model.DoesNotExist, AttributeError),
        {}
    )
```

So the exception inherits from `<model name>.DoesNotExist` and `AttributeError`.  In fact, the complete MRO for this exception type is:

```
[<class 'django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist'>, 
<class '<model module path>.DoesNotExist'>,
<class 'django.core.exceptions.ObjectDoesNotExist'>,
<class 'AttributeError'>,
<class 'Exception'>,
<class 'BaseException'>,
<class 'object'>]
```

The basic takeaway is you can catch `<model name>.DoesNotExist`, `ObjectDoesNotExist` (import from `django.core.exceptions`) or `AttributeError`, whatever makes the most sense in your context.

Answer (score 12):

Little bit late but helpful for others.

2 ways to handle this.

**1st :**

When we need to catch exception

> ```
> >>> from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
> >>> try:
> >>>     p2.restaurant
> >>> except ObjectDoesNotExist:
> >>>     print("There is no restaurant here.")
> There is no restaurant here.
> ```

**2nd:** 
When don't want to handle exception

> ```
> >>> hasattr(p2, 'restaurant')
> False
> ```

Comment: hasattr() is the right way to do it I think

Answer (score 3):

tdelaney's answer is great for regular code paths, but if you need to know how to catch this exception in tests:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

...

    def testCompanyRequired(self):
        with self.assertRaises(ObjectDoesNotExist):
            employee = Employee.objects.create()
```

Answer (score 0):

`RelatedObjectDoesNotExist` exception handling required boilterplate code everywhere, so I've changed how `OneToOneField` works. With this custom `OnetoOneField` it just returns `None` if related record doesn't exist instead of raising an exception.

```py
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.fields import related


class ReverseOneToOneDescriptor(related.ReverseOneToOneDescriptor):
    def __get__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return super().__get__(*args, **kwargs)
        except self.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist:
            pass


class OneToOneField(models.OneToOneField):
    related_accessor_class = ReverseOneToOneDescriptor
```