# Django RelatedObjectDoesNotExist error

Tags: python, django

I cannot see to get this to work...

I have a method `has_related_object` in my model that needs to check if a related object exists...

```
class Business(base):
      name =  models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)


  def has_related_object(self):
    has_customer = False
    has_car = False

    try:
        has_customer = (self.customer is not None)
    except Business.DoesNotExist:
        pass

    try:
        has_car = (self.car.park is not None)
    except Business.DoesNotExist:
        pass

    return has_customer and has_car



class Customer(base):
      name =  models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
      person = models.OneToOneField('Business', related_name="customer")
```

Error

> RelatedObjectDoesNotExist Business has no customer.

I need to check if these related objects exist but from within the business object method

Comment: What is your question? Thanks.

Comment: I need to check if these related objects exist but from within the business object method

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're trapping `except Business.DoesNotExist` but that's not the exception that's being thrown. Per [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26270785/7376) you want to catch the general [`DoesNotExist`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/exceptions/#objectdoesnotexist-and-doesnotexist) exception instead.

EDIT: see comment below: the actual exceptions are being caught by `DoesNotExist` because they inherit from `DoesNotExist`. You're better off trapping the real exception rather than suppressing any and all `DoesNotExist` exceptions from the involved models.

Comment: For the record, the exceptions being raised are `Customer.DoesNotExist` in the first case and `Car.DoesNotExist` in the second.

Comment: Is there a function that returns a boolean that I can call instead of catching the error? like ```model.DoesExists(other_model)```

Comment: just realized that I could call hasattr on it... so nevermind

Comment: @JeremyCraigMartinez ohh yaaa my problem fixed by simply call `hasattr`, thanks!

Comment: @ИскренСтаниславов - what kind of test and what happens instead?

Comment: @ИскренСтаниславов it's tough to follow that code (maybe put it in a pastebin?) but what's happening instead? This doesn't seem to be a 1:1 match to what was discussed in this question. Maybe post a new question and tag me?

Comment: @ИскренСтаниславов I think I get what you were saying now: this code didn't work for you, but that's because `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist` isn't a child of `DoesNotExist` (I'm guessing). From the links in my original answer, it looks like `ObjectDoesNotExist` is the parent of both?

Comment: I deleted my comments and added a suggestion for django unittesting